# Cannot publish to azure directory

Tags: microsoft-teams, azureportal, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am using Microsoft Graph API to send messages to private users in Microsoft Teams. I registered an App in Azure Active Directory, gave proper permissions and called the API and was able to successfully send the message. 
My question is what would be the most efficient way to deliver this integration to different clients? Do we have to register an App in every azure directory of the client individually, or is there a way I can publish the app that I have created with all the API permissions required and the administrators can install the app in their azure directory

Answer (score 0):

You would have to publish your application in your home tenant as a Multi-tenant application.

When a user from the client's tenant access your app, they will be prompted for login and post that either the user or an admin will have to consent to the app and the required permissions. This will create a service principal in the corresponding user's directory where the consent objects are stored. This way you don't have to register application in each directory.

You can follow the steps listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant) for more detailed instructions to convert your application into a multi-tenant app.

Comment: Thanks Manoj, Do we have to use subscriptions so that the app can be accessed by multiple tenants? If yes, the subscription has to be added to the developer azure directory or the client AZ directory? Also, the client can access the app using hthe app id uri in their browsers?

Comment: Subscriptions are not required for multi-tenant apps. They should be able to access the app using the App ID URL. This completely depends on the settings configured by the developer.

Comment: I have made my app multi-tenant as per the documentation but when I am trying to access the app using application-uri, it cannot be reached. Do I have to publish the app that I have registered in the Azure directory?